# Gitlab job is stuck, no active runners, why?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a step that builds a docker image. Normally, I'd have this done when a merge happens, but in this case, I want to prove it works, so I'm trying to force it to run when as part of the normal build. Yet, regardless Gitlab (the cloud version) cannot or will not find a "runner" to get this done. This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file.
The stage/step in question is

build-docker-image

This job stays in pending with the following message:

```
This job is stuck because of one of the following problems. There are no active runners online, no runners for the protected branch , or no runners that match all of the job's tags: build-docker-image
Go to project CI settings
```

```
stages:
  - build-app
  - test
  - build-docker-image
  - deploy-develop
  - deploy-staging
  - deploy-prod

variables:
  APP: myapp

##########################################
# Build
##########################################
build-app:
  stage: build-app
  image:
    name: mirror.gcr.io/library/maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17
  variables:
    GIT_DEPTH: 5
  cache:
    key: Maven
    paths:
      - .mvn/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/myapp-*.jar
    expire_in: 1 month
  tags:
    - build
  script:
    - mvn -DskipTests -Dmaven.repo.local=$(pwd)/.mvn package

##########################################
# Test
##########################################
test:
  stage: test
  image:
    name: mirror.gcr.io/library/maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17
  variables:
    GIT_DEPTH: 51
  cache:
    key: Maven
    paths:
      - .mvn/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/myapp-*.jar
    expire_in: 1 month
  tags:
    - build
  script:
    - mvn test -Dmaven.repo.local=$(pwd)/.mvn test

##########################################
# Build Docker Image
##########################################
build-docker-image:
  stage: build-docker-image
  variables:
    GIT_DEPTH: 5
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  dependencies:
    - build-app
  tags:
    - build-docker-image
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo $GCP_DOCKER | base64 -d > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - >-
      /kaniko/executor
      --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
      --dockerfile "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Dockerfile"
      --destination "us.gcr.io/mycompany-ops/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"
      --build-arg GIT_SHA=${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}
      --build-arg GIT_TAG=${CI_COMMIT_TAG}
      --build-arg BUILT_ON="$(date)"
  when: 
#  only:
#    - main
```

Comment: Do you have a runner for the tag `build-docker-image`?

Comment: Thanks @JohnKugelman. I thought all I'd need would be in that yml file. The build-app and test stages run. Why did it single out this one for some other runner?

Comment: Runners can be configured with tags of your choice when you first set them up. The purpose of `tags:` in `.gitlab-ci.yml` is to say, "only use runners with these tags". For example, if you need a job to run on a specific server, or have CUDA access, or some other special environmental thing that generic runners don't have, use tags. If that's not your intention then remove `tags:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags within `.gitlab-ci.yml` map jobs to runners. If you have no runners tagged with `build-docker-image`, then you will get the following error message:

```
This job is stuck because of one of the following problems. There are no
active runners online, no runners for the protected branch, or no runners
that match all of the job's tags: build-docker-image
```

If you want to use the same runner as other steps in your pipeline, change the following:

```yaml
##########################################
# Build Docker Image
##########################################
build-docker-image:
  stage: build-docker-image
  # ...
  tags:
    - build
  script:
  # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For others who hit this, but are wanting to use shared runners, you need to explicitly enable them for each project (Settings --> CI/CD then expand Runners).

[image]